# Adopt a question

Tags: support

I would like to "adopt" this [RHEL5 reverse tethering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49567/how-do-you-access-internet-in-rhel-5-using-android-smartphone-usb-lan) question, since I am looking for exact the same thing right now.

Is it possible to transfer ownership of that question to me?

Or: Should I ask a more detailed one and flag the original as same question?

The orignator of the q seems to be inactive - else I would just have edited his question. Drawback is that I will not get notified for new answers to that q.

Comment: Yes, ask a new and more detailed one. The one you linked to is not very clear and the OP hasn't been seen in months. Feel free to flag the old one as a dupe or just vote to close it when you post yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd ask your question and if it gets traction we can link the other as a duplicate to yours. Be sure to reference the other question in yours so that it's clear to everyone that you've seen the other question and are looking for a more specific answer to your question.